# merging multiple graphviz DOT files in Windows for gvpack

Tags: windows, cmd, doxygen, graphviz, dot

I have a large C codebase for which I had to generate Call graphs. I was kind of successful using Doxygen, but the problem now is, Doxygen generates a different DOT file for every function etc,..

I found another tool within GraphViz called `gvpack` which merges many Dot files into one, but how to make this call dynamically?? I mean the names of those dot files are random, so when I use

```
gvpack -o output.DOT *.dot
```

it says cannot open *.dot, but

```
gvpack -o output.DOT file1.dot file2.dot file3.dot
```

works fine, so my question is: is there any way to input all files (DOT) to `gvpack` by using wildcards??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the dos `type` command to combine the files using a wildcard, then pipe it to gvpack:

```
type *.dot | gvpack -o output.dot
```

From the [gvpack manual](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> gvpack [ -nguv? ] [ -mmargin
>   ] [ -array[_flags][n] ] [ -ooutfile ]
>   [ -Gname=value ] [ files ]
>
> OPERANDS
>
> *files*   Names of files containing 1 or more graphs in dot format. If no files
>   operand is specified, the standard input will be used.

Comment: wow thank u :) i was trying dir /w/b *.dot | gvpack and it was not working :)